# preventDefault on lists that have a link ánd another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where I am not able to change the HTML, I can only inject JavaScript and CSS. The website has a dropdown menu that doesn't work properly on Android. The parent menu is also a link, and when people click it they are taken to the link on the parent instead of opening the child/submenu.

The HTML (simplified)

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu ▼</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I have this jQuery:

```
var topmenuclicked == 0;
$("#menu > li a").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    if (topmenuclicked == 0) {
        topmenuclicked = 1;
    } else {
        topmenuclicked = 0;
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    }

});
```

It's a bit messy and not the best way to solve this, but my main problem is with selecting only the `a` elements that have a submenu.

**With the code as it is now I have to click all parent menu links twice and I'm not sure why.**

So I need to be able to say something like `$("#menu > li:has(ul) a)` but I don't believe that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use children("ul").length of li element

```
$("#menu > li a").click(function(event){


     //use $(this).parent().children("ul").length   
     if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
       event.preventDefault();
       // the clicked on <li> has a <ul> as a direct child
     }

    if (topmenuclicked == 0) {
        topmenuclicked = 1;
    } else {
        topmenuclicked = 0;
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    }

});
```

Comment: The clicked on element is the `a` element, so it does not have any `ul` element as a child. The `ul` is a child of the `li` the `a` is in.

Comment: Edited now , you can provide Id's to li if it is static. or use $(this).parent().children("ul").length or $(this).closest("li").children("ul").length. Check answer now

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer won't work, cause submenu is not inside of A tag, but the rest is good.

Here is how can you fix it:

```
$('#menu > li a').on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(this).next('ul').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Parent link clicked
    } else {
        // Nested link clicked
        // The ELSE part can be removed if custom logic is not needed
    }
});
```

Another option can be:

```
$('#menu > li > a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Parent link clicked
});

$('#menu > ul a').on('click', function (event) {
    // Nested link clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents` for this. Also, use `.on` instead of `.click`

```js
$('#menu').on('click', 'li a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var topmenuclicked = 0;
    if($(this).parents('ul').length == 1) {
      topmenuclicked = 1;
    }
    
    console.log('topmenuclicked -> ', topmenuclicked)

   // do your stuff here

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu ▼</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

put > before a. See below

```
var topmenuclicked == 0;
$("#menu > li > a").click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

if (topmenuclicked == 0) {
    topmenuclicked = 1;
} else {
    topmenuclicked = 0;
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In part because of @Love-Kesh his solution I came up with this that seems to be working.

```
$("#menu > li a").click(function(event){

    // save parent in variable
    var clickedlinkparent = $(this).parent();

    // check if parent has any ul element as children
    if (clickedlinkparent.children('ul').length) {

        // prevent the link from opening
        event.preventDefault();

        // if link has not been clicked, do nothing
        if (topmenuclicked == 0) {
            topmenuclicked = 1;
        // if link has already been clicked, go to href
        } else {
            topmenuclicked = 0;
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    }
});
```